# get criteria from form controls

Tags: c#, sql

I have two `MaskedTextBox` elements on a form (`MaskedTextBox1` and `MaskedTextBox1`) representing `DateFrom` and `DateTo` and one `ComboBox` (`ComboBox1`) which I have already populated from within the Collection Property section

Can you please show me how to replace the dates Between And with the `maskedTextBoxes` and the `ComboBox` to replace the `Select("branch = 'EN5'").FirstOrDefault();`

```
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT branch, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[can]/1.2)) AS [C1], 
          SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[carton]/1.2)) AS [C2], 
          SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[other])) AS [O] FROM detail 
          WHERE dates BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30'
          GROUP BY branch ", cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Select("branch = 'EN5'").FirstOrDefault();
if (dr != null)
{
    label63.Text = dr["C1"].ToString();
    label62.Text = dr["C2"].ToString();
}
```

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
+'MaskedTextBox1.Value' And +'MaskedTextBox2.Value'

Select("branch = +'ComboBox1.Value'").FirstOrDefault();
```

Have adjusted but now get error message
Incorrect syntax near keyword BETWEEN

```
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT branch, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[food]/1.2)) AS [F], 
                                   SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[drink]/1.2)) AS [D], 
                                   SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[other])) AS [O] FROM detail dates 
                                   BETWEEN " + MaskedTextBox1.Text + " And " + MaskedTextBox2.Text + " GROUP BY branch ", cn);
```

Have adjusted but now get error message
Incorrect syntax near keyword BETWEEN

Comment: Winforms or WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: Saying doesnt work doesnt help, show us an error message so we can help.

Comment: For the sanity of you and the next developer that has to dig through your code, avoid at all costs default control names like `ComboBox1`, `label62`, `label63`, `MaskedTextBox2`, etc. Think of how much clearer it would be if your boxes were named `mtbx_BeforeDate` and `mtbx_AfterDate`, you wouldn't have to switch back and forth between code/design and hunt for the right controls... Hint: To solve this, search for "C# parameterized query" on here or google.

Comment: The error message is Incorrect syntax near keyword BETWEEN. I think maskedTextBox21.Value is wrong but so is MaskedtextBox1.Text

Answer (score 0):

Simplify, then Divide and Conquer.

### First

Usually is better prepare the string so you can debug and see the value. Also you can copy the string in the SQL to see if work properly.

```
string strSQL = "SELECT branch, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[can]/1.2)) AS [C1], 
      SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[carton]/1.2)) AS [C2], 
      SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[other])) AS [O] FROM detail 
      WHERE dates BETWEEN " + MaskedTextBox1.Value + " And " + MaskedTextBox2.Value +
      "GROUP BY branch "
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, cn);
```

### Second

Is even better use [PARAMETERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) like in sql server to avoid [Sql Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
string commandText = "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics "
    + "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
```

### Third

Need use LINQ form

```
Select(b =>  b.brand == ComboBox1.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: MaskedTextBox1.Value is wrong. It should be MaskedTextBox1.Text. Is that right ? Anyway, still not working as per error message posted above

Comment: where? in the first solution is a missing space before `group`. Did you copy the resulting strSQL to your SQL and try it? I dont know what is returning MaskedTextBox.Text yet, is the right format? Also you havent say what RDBMS are you using. As I Say Divide and Conquer. Try to make a simple query then go to the complicated one. We can only give you general guidelines, you still need to try and debug because we dont have the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't build an SQL statement by concatenating strings with user-input, because this will make your application vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (please read!).

Instead you should use a parameterized query ([as shown here for example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx703tc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). In your case this would be something like this:

```
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT branch, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[can]/1.2)) AS [C1], 
      SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[carton]/1.2)) AS [C2], 
      SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),[other])) AS [O] FROM detail 
      WHERE dates BETWEEN @from AND @to
      GROUP BY branch ", cn);

sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@from", MaskedTextBox1.Value);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@to", MaskedTextBox2.Value);
```

Then you have to make sure that the user-input is in the correct format. Best way would probably be to first convert the user-input to DateTime values before adding them to the `SelectCommand.Parameters`:

```
var from = DateTime.Parse(MaskedTextBox1.Value);
var to = DateTime.Parse(MaskedTextBox2.Value);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@from", from);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@to", to);
```

(see also DateTime.TryParse).

Comment: Error Message Incorrect syntax near keyword BETWEEN

Comment: I tried your code again and now it works. Thank you.  Can you also tell me how to do the ComboBox.

Comment: Sorted out the ComboBox

Comment: @callasda: please don't forget to upvote / accept helpful answers to (all) your questions. Thanks!